# How to perform addition of column values in SAS for large dataset

Tags: sas

I have a large data set having millions of records with more than 200 columns. Is there any way to perform the sum of columns in SAS.Below is the sample data.

[image: Sample DATA]

I want to display the data as below.Like Need to SUM all the values of columns in col1 .100+100+100+100+100+100=600

[image: Desired Output]

Comment: Have a look at proc summary

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple `proc summary` will suffice.

```
proc summary data=want nway ;
  var col1-col7 ;
  output out=sum (drop=_:) sum= ;
run ;
```